# Receive email when site hosted on private server

Tags: godaddy

I have a domain name hosted at godaddy which is pointed to my ip address, where I'm running the web server. I want to use my domain name email accounts. Do I need to install my own mail server or can godaddy handle all the trouble? Thanks!

Comment: Yes: http://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, godaddy can handle your domain email accounts already so you don't have to install your own mail server. it is probably the simplest way to go.

http://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx

however, i have not been actively managing any godaddy domain for a couple of years so you need to read their latest documents and email their support if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks! what if I wanted to host my own email server. Can I rely on getting all the emails sent/received if I choose to use my own server?

Comment: In that case you should as long as you set up dns at godaddy correctly. Be careful not to be an open relay though for spammers and use a more secure server such as postfix and qmail. It is a bit more involved but you have far more control to have your own server.

Comment: @JoeWolf, in these days of GMail and many other hosted email solutions, I would not recommend running your mail server unless you want to know how to run a mail server.  If you're just interested in getting mail for your domain, running your own is probably more trouble than it's worth, unless you have specialized requirements.